# Prove $A\cup A'$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

The book suggest a bit verbose proof for that. **However, I think it's trivial because $A\cup A'$ contains each of its limit points.** Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you aren't...but still needs some proof.

Comment: What is $A$ and $A'$? What is the topological space these subsets are in?

Comment: @freakish The book just says "Prove: $A\cup A^{'}$ is a closed set". However, the chapter is about the topology on $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R^{2}}$.

Comment: If the definition of closed set is _"a set is called closed if it contains its limit points"_ then you are right. However, if it is defined, for instance, as _"a set is called closed if its complement is open"_ then you need a proof.

Comment: @Il-seobBae This statement doesn't make any sense. It can be either true or false. I find it highly unlikely that any book would said that without stating what $A$ and $A'$ are. Perhaps the book assumes that both $A$ and $A'$ are closed?

Comment: I'm asking you this because the book already covered "a set is closed if it contains its limit points". In this situation, the proof is trivial as I said, right?

Comment: Well, still there may be something to add.. We know that the limit points of $A$ is $A'$. But are you really sure that the limit points of $A\cup A'$ is $A'$?

Comment: @Il-seobBae Indeed, if both $A$ and $A'$ are closed then $A\cup A'$ contains limit points of both $A$ and $A'$. And as you said: this is trivial. But it doesn't mean that all limit points of $A\cup A'$ are either a limit point of $A$ or a limit point of $A'$. This requires a proof.

Comment: @ThePortakal Since I'm taking a introductory topology class, I have not given much thought to the possibility that you mentioned... It's a bit complicated...

Comment: @freakish At least in $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R^{2}}$, this is true?

Comment: @Il-seobBae It is true for any metric space if $A$ and $A'$ are closed. Otherwise it may or may not be true.

Comment: @freakish I see the points. Thank you...!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not trivial.

I assume that $A'$ means the set of limit points of $A$. For a set $B$, I'll denote by $\operatorname{cl}(B)$ its closure.

Since $\operatorname{cl}(A\cup A')\supseteq\operatorname{cl}(A)\supseteq A'$, we see that
$$
A\cup A'\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A\cup A')
$$
so we just need to show $A\cup A'$ is closed.

Suppose $x$ is a limit point of $A\cup A'$. If $x\in A$, then we have nothing to prove, so suppose $x\notin A$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$; then there exists $y\in A\cup A'$, $y\ne x$, with $y\in A\cup A'$. If $y\in A$, we are done. Otherwise $y\in A'\setminus A$; take a neighborhood $V$ of $y$, $V\subseteq U$; then there is $z\in A\cap V$, $z\ne y$; thus $z\in A\cap U$, $z\ne x$